# mvn compile error invalid newline character

Tags: java, maven, netty

it is my first time use mvn complile
my maven installed:

```
Maven home: D:\android\apache-maven-3.1.1
Java version: 1.7.0_40, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_40\jre
Default locale: zh_CN, platform encoding: GB18030
OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
```

i download a netty project from https://github.com/netty/netty.

after  i run mvn compile ,error as follows
..

```
\netty-3.8.0.Final\src\main\java\org\jboss\netty\util\Vi
rtualExecutorService.java:0: invalid newline character (expected: CRLF)
```

..

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-checkstyle-plugin:
2.9.1:check (check-style) on project netty: Failed during checkstyle execution:
There are 1346 checkstyle errors. -> [Help 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Checkstyle error is not severe. You can disable checkstyle plugin, put `<skip>true</skip>` in pom.xml file:

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    ...
    <plugins>
      ...
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <skip>true</skip>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      ...
    </plugins>
    ...
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

Then the project should be built successfully.

If you do not want to change your pom.xml you may set the skip to true from command line using the –D option (override the skip parameter within an execution):

```
mvn compile -Dcheckstyle.skip=true
```

Answer (score 0):

As you read from [the developer guide](http://netty.io/wiki/developer-guide.html#wiki-h3-4), you have to configure your git installation properly so it uses the native line endings.  For more information, please read the following articles:

- https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings
- http://adaptivepatchwork.com/2012/03/01/mind-the-end-of-your-line/